# What is the difference between a BlobClient and a BlobItem and BlobHierarchyItem.Blob in version 12 of Azure SDK?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to figure out the difference between when to use a `BlobClient` vs a `BlobItem` vs `BlobHierarchyItem.Blob`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet) is an object that allows you to do some operations on azure storage blobs.

---

[BlobItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobitem?view=azure-dotnet) is the Azure Storage blob object.

---

[BlobHierarchyItem.Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobhierarchyitem?view=azure-dotnet) is a Property, and the type is BlobItem.

`public Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobItem Blob { get; }`

Comment: How do I create a BlobClient from a BlobItem?

Comment: @MikeLenart `BlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainer("xxx").GetBlobClient(BlobItem.Name)`

Comment: And how do I do the reverse, ie a BlobItem from a BlobClient?